# reverse engineering an APK file to find HTTP requests in the source code

Tags: android, apk

I've extracted an apk(react native) with dex2jar and jar to java through jd-qui and also with apktool, and I can view the source code but there is no clue where are the HTTP requests in the source code.

When I intercept the apk traffic I can see all the requests to graphql endoint but I cannot see in the source code, where they are triggered or stored.

I searched the extracted source code with some keywords such as `grahpql` endpoint name, and the server address but still no result.

And the code seems not obfuscated to me, just some parts are like;

```
@Metadata(d1 = {"\000\026\n\002\030\002\n\002\020\000\n\000\n\002\020\002\n\000\n\002\030\002\n\000\bf\030\0002\0020\001J\020\020\002\032\0020\0032\006\020\004\032\0020\005H&\006\006"}, d2 = {"Lcom/x/z/E2EModule;", "", "launch", "", "intent", "Landroid/content/Intent;", "app_release"}, k = 1, mv = {1, 7, 1}, xi = 48)
public interface E2EModule {
  void launch(Intent paramIntent);
}
```

Is there any way to reach where these requests are triggered or stored on the source code?

Comment: Cross-posted from Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249656/44325